# Having trouble using output of a simple newcommand as input to another

Tags: macros

I'm trying to do something [that seems it should be] very simple but that doesn't seem to work, grateful for guidance! In brief, I want to define some lists of tags to pass to the `\usetag` command from the tagging package (https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/tagging/tagging.pdf). basically replacing:

```
\usepackage{tagging}

\usetag{topic 1, topic 2, topic 3, etc.}
```

with

```
\usepackage{tagging}

\newcommand{\alltaggedtopics}{topic 1, topic 2, topic 3, etc.}

\usetag{\alltaggedtopics}
```

with the intention of then setting more groups of tags and having something like

```
\usepackage{tagging}

\newcommand{\alltaggedtopics}{topic 1, topic 2, topic 3, etc.}

\newcommand{\alltaggedauthors}{author 1, author 2, author 3, etc.}

\usetag{\alltaggedtopics, \alltaggedauthors}
```

However, doing it via the newcommmands results in usetag being set to nothing. I'm sure that I'm making a very fundamental mistake, grateful for help identifying what it is.

Chris

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please expand the code snippets that you have posted to a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). A MWE should compile and be as *small as possible* to demonstrate your problem. It's much easier to help you if we have full working code to start from.

Comment: You need to provide an MWE.  However, I would suspect that `\edef\tmp{\alltaggedtopics, \alltaggedauthors}` followed by `\expandafter\usetag\expandafter{\tmp}` would work.

Comment: ...or define `\newcommand\Usetag[1]{\expandafter\usetag\expandafter{#1}}` and then use `\Usetag{\alltaggedtopics}`.

Comment: By the way, the fundamental mistake that I suspect you are making is that `\usetag` wants to see the list, not a macro containing the list.  Thus, the solution is to expand the list **before** `\usetag` sees it.

Comment: Thanks both, Andrew's suggested answer by defining a newcommand \Usetag works nicely, and thanks Steven for the additional explanation.  Apologies for not following proper posting etiquette, I'll try to behave next time I have a question!

Answer (score 1):

`\usetag` wants to see a list of tags, not a container of tags.

Since tags should be simple alphanumeric strings, using `\edef` on them is safe. The simplest code around the problem is with `expl3`:

```
\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% get an internal version of \usetag
\cs_new_eq:NN \chris_usetag:n \usetag
% we can define a variant with x-expansion
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \chris_usetag:n { x }
% define a user level command
\cs_new_eq:NN \xusetag \chris_usetag:x
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

After this,

```
\xusetag{\alltaggedtopics, \alltaggedauthors}
```

will work exactly as if `\usetag` were passed the lists contained in the two macros.

An equivalent version could be

```
\ExplSyntaxOff
\cs_new_protected:Npn \xusetag #1 { \exp_args:Nx \usetag { #1 } }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

but defining a variant is conceptually better.

A classical implementation might be

```
\newcommand{\xusetag}[1]{%
   \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\usetag{#1}}\x
}
```